# Can I simulate or somehow create a WPF UI thread within a Console Application or Class Library?

Tags: c#, wpf, api, task, ui-thread

I have to use an external API that for whatever reason only works as long as it is initialized and run on a WPF app's UI thread. If I spin up a task/thread that does not use the UI Synchonization Context even within a WPF test app the API does not work.

I need to make it work within a Console App, Windows Service, class library...but not WPF application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me in console application

I'm not sure whether `Dispatcher` is needed for your case or the code simply requires STA apartment state.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hello world from Dispatcher");
            }));

            Dispatcher.Run();
        });

        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();
        thread.Join();
    }
}
```

You just need to add `WindowsBase.dll` reference for `Dispatcher`.